# animationStart event not cross-browser?

Tags: javascript, dom-events, css-animations, dom-manipulation

I am using a [recent trick to discover new nodes added to DOM](http://davidwalsh.name/detect-node-insertion) in a library that makes it comfortable to use.

It's a technique that uses `animationStart` event after a simple (not visible) animation is declared. Every time you add a new node that should be animated - the event would fire.

I have just discovered that when an element matching the selector for CSS animation is **shown** by setting `display:inline` (but existed before the animation was even declared) - **the `animationStart` fires in webkit, but not in FireFox.**

I honestly don't know which is the correct behaviour and if this is only about a certain version of one of my browsers.

At the end of chapter3-animations the W3C document says animations should run after the element is shown. http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-animations/#animations

The fifth test case [here](http://naugtur.github.com/insertionQuery/) is the one affected by the problem.

What is the reason for this difference between browsers? Or how do I make it consistent?

Comment: If you get different test results in your browser, please report it in a coment instead of an answer.

Comment: So, it was `display:none` before?

Comment: Yes, `el.style.display='none'; document.body.appendChild(el);` and `el.style.display='inline'` after creating the animation and event handler.

Comment: I don't see a question anywhere.  What is the question you want help with?

Comment: I stated the question more clearly. Hope that's how I get it to work.